# XML serialization related question and c#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Suppose i have one `customer` class and i will serialize the class to `xml`. After serialization we will get xml data but i need some property of `customer` class to be serialized on demand based on few condition. Is it possible?

I have no concept how to do it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one or more `ShouldSerializeXXXXXX()` methods, where `XXXXXX` is the name of each property you want to serialize based on a condition.

E.g.:

```
public class Customer
{
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public string SomeInfo { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public string SomeOtherInfo { get; set; }

    #region Serialization conditions

    // should SomeInfo be serialized?
    public bool ShouldSerializeSomeInfo()
    {
         return SomeInfo != null; // serialize if not null
    }

    // should SomeOtherInfo be serialized?
    public bool ShouldSerializeSomeOtherInfo()
    {
         return SomeOtherInfo != null; // serialize if not null
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx) and overide the [`XmlIgnore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) attribute for your property.

(there is an example in the [`XmlIgnore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) msdn page)